# How to use merge windows unallocated space into Ubuntu using GParted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I deleted my dual boot Windows part from GParted. Now this unallocated space of the windows, I want merge them into sda5. But I don't know how to do this. Have seen many post regarding this like drag to left to give the space but while trying to do this using **Resize/move**, that it's max size is already 600 GB so I can't merge that 300 GB into it. I think I'm doing it wrong. What is the right way to do this?

[image: this is the image of my gparted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice on the lef hand side of the partitions the little "key" icon. That means that the partition is locked and that's why you can't resize it. The reason it's locked is because it's mounted; it's mounted when you boot.

Here's the easiest way to do what you want: boot from a live Ubuntu CD which won't automatically mount the hard drive partitions. When you open parted, you'll notice that the key icons are gone. Good! Now resize the partition.